# How to prove a probability measure is relatively compact？

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

$\{\mu_{\alpha}\}$ is a series of probability measure corresponding to random variables $\{X_{\alpha}\}$. If $\exists r>0,M>0,s.t.\forall \alpha,\mathbb E|X_{\alpha}|^r<M,$ then $\mu_{\alpha}$ is  relatively compact.

I know that if $X_{\alpha}$ is defined in a  complete separable space, then I just need to prove $\mu_{\alpha}$ is tight based on 'prohorov theorem'  and it will be easier .

But generally, how can I get this statement?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really don't think you're going to get any general answer. I mean, write down that expected value and see if you can bound it... or... try other things...

Comment: @ Jack M  I mean if $X_{\alpha}$ is defined in a general metric space, how can I prove this statement

Comment: You are asking, why does a uniform moment bound imply tightness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly $\mu_{\alpha}$ is a family of Borel  probability measures on $\mathbb R$ with $\sup _{\alpha} \int |x|^{r}\, d\mu (x) <\infty$ and you want to show that $\{\mu_{\alpha}\}$ is tight. The domain of $X_{\alpha}$'s does not come i not the picture at all. (You are probably saying that the basic probability space is a complete separable metric space with some given Borel  probability measure but this has no realtion to the tightness question). Since $\mu_{\alpha} \{x:|x|>A\} \leq \frac 1 {A^{r}} \sup _{\alpha} \int |x|^{r}\, d\mu_{\alpha} (x)$ we see that $\{\mu_{\alpha}\}$ is tight. PS: if the random variables take values in a metric space then $E|X_{\alpha}|^{r}$ does not even make sense, so I am assuming that $X_{\alpha}$'s are real valued.

Comment: Thanks very much.Maybe you are right.